# changing this root view setup

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have been following this tutorial to set up a tableview with storyboarding.

It's all working, except in the beginning of the tutorial he starts with a tabBarView template and he embeds a UINavigationControl in that.

So this is the code that he comes up with - which works:

```
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = 
(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController = 
[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

AlbumViewController *albumsViewController = 
[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
albumsViewController.albums = albums;
```

Which is part of:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
albums = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
Album *album1 = [[Album alloc] init];
Album *album2 = [[Album alloc] init];
Album *album3 = [[Album alloc] init];
Album *album4 = [[Album alloc] init];
Album *album5 = [[Album alloc] init];

album1.albumName = @"Graduation";
album2.albumName = @"Dark and Twisted Fantasy";
album3.albumName = @"Torches";
album4.albumName = @"Nothing But The Beat";
album5.albumName = @"Angles";

album1.artist = @"Kanye West";
album2.artist = @"Kanye West";
album3.artist = @"Foster The People";
album4.artist = @"David Guetta";
album5.artist = @"The Strokes";

album1.rating = 5;
album2.rating = 5;
album3.rating = 5;
album4.rating = 5;
album5.rating = 5;

[albums addObject:album1];
[albums addObject:album2];
[albums addObject:album3];
[albums addObject:album4];
[albums addObject:album5];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = 
(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController = 
[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

AlbumViewController *albumsViewController = 
[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
albumsViewController.albums = albums;

// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}
```

This part is posted in the AppDelegate.m
I am really trying everything, but nothing works.

Any Help would be great:-)

PS If I take out the tabView or comment out the first bit of code, the TableView shows, but there is no data  in it.

Cheers Jeff

Comment: What doesn't work? What aren't you seeing that you hope to see?

Comment: So Basically I want to set up a UITableView with the data in the app delegate as per the tutorial, but I do not want to start of with a TabBarController. So basically as it is there but if you look at the first part of the code, it sets the TabBar as the root controller - however as soon as I touch that and change it, I loose the data in the Table.

Comment: So you have removed the tab view from the storyboard, and you just have a navigation controller with a table view controller in it, or just the table view controller?

Comment: Yes - I have removed the TabBarViewController, both in the code and in the SB, I have remade the app based on a ViewController and a UINavigationController - I have copy and pasted everything mixed back and forward:-) I am out of ideas:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

Here, the code is getting the root view controller of the window, which from the original project was a tab bar controller. You have removed this, so this will be returning a navigation controller.

You've removed a level of containment from the view controller hierarchy. Your root view controller is now a navigation controller. So, I think the code you need is:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
AlbumViewController *albumsViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];        
albumsViewController.albums = albums;
```

Comment: Ok yup that worked - now is it also possible to put start this with a normal UIViewController? so no navigation or tab bar??

Comment: Yes, just set the view controller as the initial view controller in your storyboard, then that will be your windows root view controller after launching.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my request - I meant to ask for UINavigationController to a UIViewController. I can then connect to the UITableView via a Segue:-)